# If opcache is open, why does my new code work even without any php-fpm restart?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, fpm, opcache

Anybody help? When I enable opcache, shouldn't I restart php-fpm it every time I update the code? I'm not restarting it, but my new code is running immediately.

Here's my opcache setup: https://ibb.co/rkvTcyk

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `opcache.validate_timestamps` enabled. From the docs:

> ```
> opcache.validate_timestamps boolean
> ```
>
> If enabled, OPcache will check for updated scripts every `opcache.revalidate_freq`
> seconds. When this directive is disabled, you must reset OPcache manually via `opcache_reset()`, `opcache_invalidate()` or by restarting the Web server for changes to the filesystem to take effect.

As you have an `opcache.revalidate_freq` of `2` your server will check for updates to the file every 2 seconds.

Comment: Was a very clear answer, thank u so much

Comment: Then mark it as accepted.